# fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory on 32bit

Tags: c, linux, 32-bit

When compiling my program in 32bit using

```
gcc -m32 program.c -o program
```

I get the following error  fatal error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory

but with

```
gcc program.c -o program
```

it works fine

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Install 32-bit headers and libs (Linux? OS X?)

Answer (score 0):

my personal similar problem was solved as below:
by the way I am using cygwin.
The reason behind this error is trying to compile a unix c socket example in a window environment. 
If you want to use windows, I think you should have cygwin installed with all the libraries needed for compiling c programs ;"gcc is the one used for generated Your_program_in_exe ".
Then start with compiling the server the server.follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C) tutorial to understand about the basic of sockets. 
You should have a client and a server programs.then go(using cd command) to the directory where you stored your code and perform the commands:

1- **gcc socket-Server.c -o server** to generate the execution file for the server.
this will generate **server.exe** file which will allow you to use **./server.exe** to run the sever on your PC.if there is no error in your file you should have the .exe file in the your directory.

2- **gcc socket-client.c -o client** to generate the execution file for the client. This will generate the file **client.exe** file which allows you to execute the client.if there is no error u should have the **client.exe** together with ur **server.exe** in the file directory.
the screen capture below shows the commands i used and the basic output[image]