# sys/socket.h fatal error trying to compile 32 bit library on 64 bit Linux platform

Tags: c, linux

I use Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit. gcc-5-multilib, g++-5-multilib, libc6-i386, kernel headers  and all build toolchain  are installed. When I try to compile 32 bit library (for linux) like:

```
gcc -m32 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib.so -o mylib.so mylib.c
```

I get an error:

```
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:345:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to compile a code with `#include <sys/socket.h>` on 64 bit for 32 bit linux?

Comment: See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496635/fatal-error-sys-socket-h-no-such-file-or-directory-on-32bit?rq=1#comment23677965_16496635

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1272420/694576

Comment: [THIS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208594) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the path of asm. Just check the path and link like this. Depending on system path may vary. Most of the time downloading `gcc-multilib` solve this issue.

```
$cd /usr/include
$sudo ln -s asm-generic/ asm
```

OR

```
$cd /usr/include
$sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/asm asm
```

Comment: @alk I think he is facing path issue. It may resolve the problem.

Comment: The is a *cross* compile question. I for example doubt the x64 assembler snippets would help to compile 32bit programs

Comment: @Rocoder It compiles and seems working, but I don't sure yet if it works correct

Comment: It may work after installing 32 bit library and will have to mention full path.

Comment: @Rocoder I have gcc-5-multilib installed. I can't install gcc-multilib, it will delete all crosscompilers. But with `sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/asm asm` I have comiled th library. It is linkable to 32 bit application on my system and do the staff. May be on real 32 bit it will not work.

Comment: @РоманКоптев I have gcc version 5.2.1 20151010. and i faced same issue while compiling the server code using -m32. I updated gcc-mulitlib it started working. you may try this command to get the arch info `file mylib.so`.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1300211 for how this is a multilib/multiarch issue with (currently) no clear correct solution to support both.